# google oauth2 on sub-subdomain - not a valid origin

Tags: google-oauth

I have setup a project on google developer console to use OAuth2 from google. The OAuth2 api works correctly when using a domain (www.mydomain.com) or subdomain (subdomain.mydomain.com) after whitelisting.

But it returns "Not a valid origin for the client" when using sub-subdomain i.e http://sub1.subdomain.mydomain.com. I have whitelisted this on Google credential page.

Below is the error that I get:

"Not a valid origin for the client: http://xxxx.test.mydomain.com:4200 has not been whitelisted for client ID 653418104263-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID."

**Note**: masked the values in message with xxx but the actual values in the message match the values on Google developer console.

**Update:** A day after updating the URL, it started working. I am not sure what was the reason as usually the URLs are acceptable instantly.

Comment: are you sure  sub-subdomain are allowed?

Comment: Allowed as in where? They are valid urls on internet.

Comment: Dosent mean Google will support you using it

Comment: Yeah, so need to know if its not supported and if there is a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

if you added `http://sub1.subdomain.mydomain.com` to the whitelist and its complaining about `http://sub1.subdomain.mydomain.com:4200`

It needs to match exactly you need to add the port.  Google is nice the error message tells you what uri you need to whitelist.

Comment: The port number is there. I added the same url that google error reported.

Comment: take a screen shot of your settings please.  Feel free to block out enough that i cant read your domain if you like.   And add your code to your question so that i can test it.   In the mean time i am sending an email off to the oauth team see if someone can verify that sub sub domains are valid.

Comment: Strangely, a day after updating the URL, it has started working. Thanks @DaImTo for your replies.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the whitelist". There is an OAuth consent screen tab with an Authorized Domains section. This only lets you enter top private domains, so you cannot specify http, https, subdomains, or port numbers. If you enter the top private domain, it works with that domain and subdomains, but not sub, sub domains, which is what this question is asking about.